# sort_values() method in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, pandas

I have the following subset of data and I need to sort the `Education` column in ascending order; from `0 to 17`.

[image]

I tried the following code without success.

```
suicide_data.sort_index(axis=0, kind='mergesort')
```

also...

```
suicide_data.Education.sort_values()
```

and...

```
suicide_data.sort_values('Education')
```

Here is the error I'm getting...

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

The documentation says that `str` can be sort with the `sort_values()` method. Does anyone know how to sort the `Education` column in ascending order?

Comment: Do you want to sort the entire DataFrame _by_ the `education` column or do you just want to reassign the column to be sorted (which doesn't seem sensible)?

Comment: I want to sort the entire dataframe by the Education column sorted in ascending order

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you must have mixed types within the `Education` column of your DataFrame. The error message is telling you that it cannot compare the strings *to* the floats in your column. Assuming you want to sort the values numerically, you could convert them to integer type and *then* sort. I'd advise you do this anyways, as mixed types won't be too useful for any operations in your DataFrame. Then use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

```
suicide_data['Education'] = suicide_data['Education'].astype('int')
suicide_data.sort_values(by='Education')
```

---

It is also worth pointing out that your first attempt,

```
suicide_data.sort_index(axis=0, kind='mergesort')
```

would sort your DataFrame by the index, which you don't want, and your second attempt

```
suicide_data.Education.sort_values()
```

would only return the sorted Series - they are completely invalid approaches.

Answer (score 3):

```
suicide_data['Education'].sort_values('Education', ascending = 'True')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.