# If "n" not monolitic increasing replace "n" with "n-1"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any good recipe to go lets say from:

```
datetime value
2021-10-05 09:39:00 1
2021-10-05 09:40:00 2
2021-10-05 09:41:00 3
2021-10-05 09:42:00 2 <--
2021-10-05 09:43:00 3
```

to:

```
datetime value
2021-10-05 09:39:00 1
2021-10-05 09:40:00 2
2021-10-05 09:41:00 3
2021-10-05 09:42:00 3 <--
2021-10-05 09:43:00 3
```

in python/pandas?

thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort\_values() method in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477572/sort-values-method-in-pandas)

Comment: You mean "monotonically increasing"; not monolithic.

Comment: @sushanth That question is definitely not a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

Test rows with not monotonically increasing by compare difference for not equal `-1` and then replace by shifted values:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].where(df['value'].diff().ne(-1), df['value'].shift(-1))
print (df)
   id  value
0   0      1
1   0      2
2   0      3
3   0      3
4   0      3
```

If possible multiple values not monotonically increased is better use `backfill` not matched values:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].where(df['value'].diff().ne(-1)).bfill().astype(int)
print (df)
   id  value
0   0      1
1   0      2
2   0      3
3   0      3
4   0      3
```

Comment: @jezrael What i forgot to add is that i need it like a meter. So if the series is like that '[8,9,9,9,1,1,2]', nothing shoud be changed.

Comment: @Mischbot - it is not changed, because starting by `1` ?

Comment: @jezrael - yes.

Comment: @Mischbot - `df['value'] = df['value'].where(df['value'].diff().ne(-1)).bfill().astype(int)` working well for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two steps:

- set the corresponding value to NaN, by testing if the next value (shfited value) is equal or larger than the previous value.
- fill the NaNs with the previous value

Of course, this doesn't work if there are NaNs in the input. But in that case, monotonically increasing doesn't mean anything anymore.

```
In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(5), 'value': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]}).set_index('id')

In [62]: df.loc[df['value'].shift() >= df['value'], 'value'] = np.nan

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
    value
id
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     NaN
4     3.0

In [64]: df['value'].fillna(method='bfill')
Out[64]:
id
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean by:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].cummax()
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['value'] < df['value'].shift(), 'value'] += 1
```

Both codes give:

```
>>> df
   id  value
0   0      1
1   1      2
2   2      3
3   3      3
4   4      3
>>>
```

Comment: The second, and not +1. The question is in the title.

Comment: Both answers not test `monolitic increasing`